# How to display 5 numbers per line from a list?

Tags: python

How to display 5 numbers per line from a list?

```
lx = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25] 

def display(lx):

    for i in range(0,len(lx), 5):
        x = lx[i:i +5]
    return x

print(display(lx))
```

my current code is displaying only one line that contains 5 numbers, and the expected should be 5 lines that contains 5 numbers per line

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to print lines of numbers with each line having 5  consecutive numbers on it from the list?

Comment: Yes, Tom Conboy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the function a generator by making it yield the sliced lists instead:

```
def display(lx):
    for i in range(0, len(lx), 5):
        yield lx[i:i + 5]

print(*display(lx), sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
[17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
[22, 23, 24, 25]
```

Comment: Would be nice to pass `5` as a parameter as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

def printer(lis, num_per_line):
    z = 1
    for each_num in lis:
        if z%(num_per_line) == 0:
            print(each_num, end='\n')
        else:
            print(each_num, end='\t')
        z+=1    

printer(x, 5)
```

Use this function where you need to pass the list and entities to be printed in a single line.

The output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [55, 26, 59, 35, 28, 22, 33, 43, 49, 45, 20, 11, 34, 44, 57, 12, 16, 31, 32, 58, 15, 38, 37, 48, 39]

def display(lst):
    x = 0
    while x in range(len(lst)):
        print(lst[x:x+5])
        x+=5
#Output

[55, 26, 59, 35, 28]
[22, 33, 43, 49, 45]
[20, 11, 34, 44, 57]
[12, 16, 31, 32, 58]
[15, 38, 37, 48, 39]
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be different approaches to the problem:

```
x=[]  #your given list
for t in range(len(x)):
    if(t%5==0):
        print('\n')
    print(str(x[t])+'\t',end='')  #end will print numbers on same line otherwise
```

this code will give the desired output..